# Configuration Injection Framework

Tags: java, dependency-injection, code-injection

I recently stumbled upon the following [Configuration Injection](http://bitbucket.org/schildmeijer/coin/wiki/Home) Framework. Seems interesting and seems to fit my needs. Has anyone tried it or knows about some other Configuration Injection frameworks? As far as I know Spring and Google Guice does not support this kinds of injection?

Comment: I made it because I did not want to include guidc or spring in my application. currently theres only a snapshot available. but feel free to use it, check the source code, and post me some feature requests.

Comment: a new release (0.3.0) is now available on http://bitbucket.org/schildmeijer/coin/wiki/Home

Answer (score 2):

In Spring you can do something similiar with the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer, look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s07.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer

Answer (score 0):

[Constretto](http://constretto.org/) with spring may provide what you need. Spring also does most of these things, especially in version 3.0